# Magento 1.9 > Manage Products > Images browse files button not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am new user for magento 1.9 site. I am facing the issue - Magento browse files button not working.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your browser's Flash plugin up to date?

Comment: Try this html5 solution: https://www.mavenecommerce.com/2016/10/18/magento-html5-uploader/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried google?

Check out this link, it may help you:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons

Comment: yes i have checked this. I have displayed both buttons for browse and upload. But, Browse Files button not working.

Comment: I remember I had the same error a time ago. Please check you console (F12 in browser -> Console) and check the output. Maybe there's a javascript error?

Comment: yes, Now its working on Chrome browser but not in firefox. Please Suggest.

Comment: maybe flash is disabled in Firefox? https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-firefox.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the attached screenshot,you need to click on site-padlock icon on left hand corner before URL. A list appears on click of padlock you need to Expand the options of Flash and select "**Always allow on this site**".

Refresh the page and flash buttons will be there.

[image]